# How to change the background color which uses degraded colors, according to the value of the Slider in Xamarin Forms?

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have a ListView which has each element a Slider. What I need is to be able to change the background color with other colors when the Slider has values ​​between <20 and> 2.
What I have at the moment is a class in which converts the 2 two colors sent to a gradient background, which is shown below.
In addition, what I can do is that when the screen is loaded, the conversion is made to degraded colors. But when I want to modify the values ​​to be able to change colors when the Slider has values ​​between <20 and> 2, the operation is not performed.

```
//Clase para convertir en colores degradados
public class ValueToTextConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if ((double)value < 20 && (double)value > 2)
        {
            return "Editado";
        }

        return "Ejemplo";
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

//Pagina principal: Archivo XAML
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:PruebasXamarin" 
         xmlns:local2="clr-namespace:PruebasXamarin.CustomControls; assembly:PruebasXamarin"
         x:Class="PruebasXamarin.MainPage">
<ContentPage.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <local:ValueToTextConverter x:Key="ValueToText"/>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</ContentPage.Resources>
<ContentPage.Content>

    <local2:GradientColorStack StartColor="{Binding PrimerColor, Mode=OneWay}" EndColor="{Binding SegundoColor, Mode=OneWay}">
    <StackLayout x:Name="colorBa">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="8*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Label x:Name="label" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" FontSize="Large"
                                        FontAttributes="Bold"
                                        HorizontalOptions="Center"
                                        TextColor="White"/>

        </Grid>

        <ListView x:Name="ListaTareas" SeparatorVisibility="None"
                      HasUnevenRows="True">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <StackLayout>
                            <Grid Margin="10" ColumnSpacing="0" BackgroundColor="White" >
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="8"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>


                                <Label 
                                            Grid.Row="0"
                                            Grid.Column="1"
                                            Text="{Binding nombre}" 
                                            TextColor="Black" 
                                            FontSize="14"
                                            FontAttributes="Bold"
                                            Margin="4"
                                            BackgroundColor="White"/>

                                <Slider x:Name="mySlider"
                                        Grid.Row="0"
                                        Grid.Column="2"
                                        Minimum="0"
                                        Maximum="4"
                                        Value="{Binding valor}"
                                        ValueChanged="mySlider_ValueChanged"></Slider>
                                <Label 
                                            Grid.Row="0"
                                            Grid.Column="3"
                                            Text="{Binding Source={x:Reference mySlider},Path=Value,Converter={StaticResource ValueToText}}" 
                                            TextColor="Black" 
                                            FontSize="14"
                                            FontAttributes="Bold"
                                            Margin="4"
                                            BackgroundColor="White"
                                            HorizontalOptions="End"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </StackLayout>
    </local2:GradientColorStack>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

//Pagina principal: Archivo cs

```
namespace PruebasXamarin
{
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage, INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    readonly List<Tarea> listaTarea = new List<Tarea>();
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;


    private string primerColor, segundoColor;
    public string PrimerColor
    {
        get
        {
            return this.primerColor;
        }
        set
        {
            if (this.primerColor != value)
            {
                this.primerColor = value;
                PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(this.PrimerColor)));
            }
        }
    }
    public string SegundoColor 
    { 
        get
        {
            return this.segundoColor;
        } 
        set
        {
            if (this.segundoColor != value)
            {
                this.segundoColor = value;
                PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(this.SegundoColor)));
            }
        }
    }


    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        llenarLista();
        ListaTareas.ItemsSource = listaTarea;
        BindingContext = this;
    }
    public void llenarLista()
    {

        listaTarea.Add(new Tarea
        {
            nombre = "Alex1",
            valor = "10",
            descripcion = "Ejemplo"
        });
        listaTarea.Add(new Tarea
        {
            nombre = "Alex2",
            valor = "20",
            descripcion = "Ejemplo"
        });


        this.PrimerColor = "#0CABA1";
        this.SegundoColor = "#A9AB0C";

        //primerColor = "#AB0C2E";
        //segundoColor = "#0C6AAB";
    }

    private void mySlider_ValueChanged(object sender, ValueChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var sliders = sender as Slider;
        var item = sliders.Parent.BindingContext as Tarea;


        this.PrimerColor = "#AB0C2E";
        this.SegundoColor = "#0C6AAB";
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Have you tried changing the colors on a main thread ?

Comment: Which control's background color do you want to modify?

Comment: The wallpaper. This is done by aki in the ...
<local2: GradientColorStack StartColor = "{Binding FirstColor, Mode = OneWay}" EndColor = "{Binding SecondColor, Mode = OneWay}">

Comment: @AlexGD Thanks for replying,I have updated an answer.When you have time , you can check it .

Answer (score 0):

You should use [CustomRenderer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/renderers) here.

1. Here is a sample renderer for [GradientColorStackRenderer](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/horizontal-and-vertical-gradient-color-in-xamarin-forms/) you
   can refer to first.
2. If you have be ready for this article, you also add
   `OnElementPropertyChanged` in renderer

GradientColorStack.cs is different from article:

```
public class GradientColorStack : StackLayout
{
    public GradientColorStack()
    {

    }

    public static readonly BindableProperty StartColorProperty = BindableProperty.Create("StartColor", typeof(Color), typeof(GradientColorStack), null);

    public Color StartColor
    {
        get { return (Color)GetValue(StartColorProperty); }
        set { SetValue(StartColorProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly BindableProperty EndColorProperty = BindableProperty.Create("EndColor", typeof(Color), typeof(GradientColorStack), null);

    public Color EndColor
    {
        get { return (Color)GetValue(EndColorProperty); }
        set { SetValue(EndColorProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

**For Android：**

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(GradientColorStack), typeof(GradientColorStackRenderer))]
namespace App10.Droid
{
    public class GradientColorStackRenderer : ViewRenderer
    {

        public GradientColorStackRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
        {

        }

        private Color StartColor
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
        private Color EndColor
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
        protected override void DispatchDraw(global::Android.Graphics.Canvas canvas)
        {
            #region for Vertical Gradient  
            //var gradient = new Android.Graphics.LinearGradient(0, 0, 0, Height,      
            #endregion
            #region  for Horizontal Gradient  
            var gradient = new Android.Graphics.LinearGradient(0, 0, Width, 0,
            #endregion
            this.StartColor.ToAndroid(),
            this.EndColor.ToAndroid(),
            Android.Graphics.Shader.TileMode.Mirror);
            var paint = new Android.Graphics.Paint()
            {
                Dither = true,
            };
            paint.SetShader(gradient);
            canvas.DrawPaint(paint);
            base.DispatchDraw(canvas);
        }

        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Xamarin.Forms.View> e)
        {
            if (e.OldElement != null || Element == null)
            {
                return;
            }
            try
            {
                var stack = e.NewElement as GradientColorStack;
                this.StartColor = stack.StartColor;
                this.EndColor = stack.EndColor;
                Console.WriteLine("OnElementChanged:");
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("ERROR:", ex.Message);
            }
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

        }

        protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnElementPropertyChanged(sender, e);
            Console.WriteLine("OnElementPropertyChanged:");

            var stack = sender as GradientColorStack;
            if(e.PropertyName == nameof(stack.StartColor))
            {
                this.StartColor = stack.StartColor;
            }
            if (e.PropertyName == nameof(stack.EndColor))
            {
                this.EndColor = stack.EndColor;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

[image: Then it can work now]

**For IOS** :Here is a bit difference.Need to set listview's backgroudcolor be `BackgroundColor="Transparent"`.

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(GradientColorStack), typeof(GradientColorStackRenderer))]
namespace App10.iOS
{
    public class GradientColorStackRenderer : ViewRenderer
    {

        CAGradientLayer gradientLayer;
        public GradientColorStackRenderer()
        {
            gradientLayer = new CAGradientLayer();
        }

        public override void Draw(CGRect rect)
        {
            GradientColorStack stack = (GradientColorStack)this.Element;
            CGColor startColor = stack.StartColor.ToCGColor();
            CGColor endColor = stack.EndColor.ToCGColor();
            #region for Vertical Gradient  
            //var gradientLayer = new CAGradientLayer();     
            #endregion
            #region for Horizontal Gradient  
            //var gradientLayer = new CAGradientLayer()
            //{
            //    StartPoint = new CGPoint(0, 0.5),
            //    EndPoint = new CGPoint(1, 0.5)
            //};
            #endregion
            gradientLayer.Frame = rect;
            gradientLayer.Colors = new CGColor[] {
                startColor,
                endColor
            };

            NativeView.Layer.InsertSublayer(gradientLayer, 0);
            base.Draw(rect);
        }

        protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnElementPropertyChanged(sender, e);
            Console.WriteLine("OnElementPropertyChanged");
            SetNeedsDisplay();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the [Sample link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/0a6mlmpfg25tip9/App10.rar?dl=0).